# unigry giftcertificates and reporting

Tags: magento

I have a task for my client that involves unigry gift certificates on Magento.  The client has asked me to only report in sales reports (and dashboard) when the gift certificate is applied, and not when purchased.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about this and was wondering if someone (who may have experience with this) can recommend a strategy of attack.   Thanks!

Comment: Just an update, the client also wants me to convert the gift card to a  customer credit on application of the gift card.  I believe this might  actually partially fulfill the above requirement since credits aren't shown in reporting.  The only thing is to not include the gift certificate purchase in reporting.  Maybe deleting and/or modifying the entry in mage_sales_flat_order?

Answer (score 1):

Unirgy Gift Certificate is a paid extension! Contact support!